# 16.04 LTS won't boot after updating

Tags: 16.04, lts

Updated using the sudo update command and now my system won't boot.Booted into boot repair on a flash drive and ran the program but it still won't boot. Here is a link the the boot repair output file.
https://paste.ubuntu.com/21808545/